# Allure serve command to update realtime and make use of the advanced features(trends, history, etc)

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, allure

The way I am creating the Allure report is by creating the XMLs with the allure plugin for pytest, like so

```
pytest LoginTest.py --alluredir C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Allure\xml
```

Here will generate a hand-full of XMLs and txt files. As expected.

Next I serve the Allure with these XMLs, like so.

```
allure serve C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Allure\xml --port 9000
```

This then kicks off the Allure server and displays me the test results in the correct fashion and everything is great.

However, if I were to run the same test again and make it fail, for example - the server doesnt update automatically, I have to kill it and re-run the 2nd command. Surely there is a way for it to automatically notice new XMLs and update accordingly? Or am I missing something?

I also do not understand how to make use of the other features of Allure, (trends, history, etc). I have looked at Github, documentation, etc - and cant seem to find an answer to help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no runtime report feature is available at the moment.

The right way to use history features is using one of Allure CI plugins (Jenkins/TeamCity/Bamboo). In case you need to use it locally all you need is copy `history` folder from previous report to `allure-results` and then generate the report as usual.

Comment: Cheers for clearing this up - Where exactly is this `Allure-results` directory, I cant find it anywhere.

Comment: In your case it is `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Allure\xml`

Comment: Ahaa! Perfect! Thank you for helping me out! Is it planned to have Allure to make use of displaying the updated `allure-results` dir in a future release or?

Comment: yeah, probably in version 3.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the docker container to see your reports automatically updated.

https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service/tree/master/allure-docker-python-pytest-example

https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service